# Objectify - get all of a type regardless of parent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have child entities with @Parent key ref in them.

When I give the parent key, I am able to get the child entity like this:

```
OfyService.ofy()
            .load()
            .type(Child.class)
            .parent(parentKey)
            .id(childId).now();
```

I tried to access the child entity directly without giving the parent key, but that doesn't work (returns null):

```
OfyService.ofy()
            .load()
            .type(Child.class)
            .id(childId).now();
```

Is there another way to query one or all instances of a kind regardless of parent?

For example, _ah/admin is able to list all the entities of a Kind regardless of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Iterable<Child> children = ofy().load().type(Child.class);
```

Comment: If I defined the entity with a parent, the query only works if I set the parent(par) again like in my first code example.

Comment: The query works. You are probably seeing the results of eventual consistency. Loading by parent()/id() is a shorthand for load-by-key, which is strongly consistent. Getting all entities is a query on an index (in this case, the key index) which is always eventually consistent.

Comment: If you're executing this in your test cases, the best thing to do is turn off eventual consistency in tests. There's a method on the datastore helper named something like `setApplyAllJobRepPolicy()`

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My first time dealing with eventual consistency. .. its trickier than async because, with async, at least I get a callback when its ready.

Comment: @Teddy can you accept the answer if that worked for you?.

Comment: I did a workaround.. I got all the parent keys, and then iterated and queried the child keys. I was hoping to remove this workaround and try the fix suggested by @stickfigure, and then accept the answer once its done.